# Efficient Compare of two LIST of Lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I am a newbie to python and just learning things as i do my project and here i have two list of list which i need to compare and separate the diff found in A -- > B and diff found b --> A
What is the best way of comparing.

```
A=[[1L, 'test_case_1'], [1L, 'test_case_2'], [2L, 'test_case_1']]
B=[[1L, 'test_case_1'], [1L, 'test_case_4'], [2L, 'test_case_1'], [2L, 'test_case_3']]
```

Comment: This isn't a really good data structure to compare efficiently. If you had lists of *tuples* you could convert one to a set. This small change would allow you to compare in linear time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you can use a list of *tuples* as per my comment, this simple modification of Junuxx's answer is much more efficient

A - B:

```
>>> setb = set(B)
>>> [x for x in A if not x in setb]
[(1L, 'test_case_2')]
```

B - A:

```
>>> seta = set(A)
>>> [x for x in B if not x in seta]
[(1L, 'test_case_4'), (2L, 'test_case_3')]
```

Comment: I have seen your other answers too about fast way of computation in Python. Do you have any blog where you keep more of these?

Comment: Why not simply `seta - setb` or `setb - seta` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with a list comprehension,

A - B:

```
>>> [x for x in A if not x in B]
[[1L, 'test_case_2']]
```

B - A:

```
>>> [x for x in B if not x in A]
[[1L, 'test_case_4'], [2L, 'test_case_3']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [List Comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

**A - B:**

```
>>>[p for p in A if p not in B]
[[1L, 'test_case_2']]
```

**B - A:**

```
>>>[p for p in B if p not in A]
[(1L, 'test_case_4'), (2L, 'test_case_3')]
```

A fast way： first can make the `B` to a `set()`, then use **[Generator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions)**

For **A - B:**

```
>>>B = [(l[0], l[1]) for l in B]
>>>set_b = set(B)
>>>(p for p in A if p not in set_b)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00BCBBE8>
```

Comment: Have you tried this? `set(B)` results in `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.

Comment: @Junuxx first should translate the `B` to `tuple of list`