# Comparing list of list of list

Tags: python, list

I want to compare two `list of list of lists` and replace items in the first list that is different in the second list. What I want is that since `List1[0][2][0:3]` is the same as `List2[0][2][0:3]`, but their last elements are different, replace `List1[0][2][-1]` with `List2[0][2][-1]`. I have worked with list of lists and many examples on SO such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113106/efficient-compare-of-two-list-of-lists-in-python) deal with that but I don't know how to go about a comparison for a list of list of lists also, both lists are not always uniform in the real data set.

List1

```
[[['192', '177', '4', '749'], ['192', '177', '5', '749'], ['192', '177', '6', '999999']], [['192', '178', '1', '999999'], ['192', '178', '2', '999999'], ['192', '178', '3', '999999'], ['192', '178', '4', '999999'], ['192', '178', '5', '1511'], ['192', '178', '6', '999999']]]
```

List2

```
[[['192', '177', '4', '749'], ['192', '177', '5', '749'], ['192', '177', '6', '222222']], [['192', '178', '1', '222222'], ['192', '178', '2', '222222'], ['192', '178', '3', '222222'], ['192', '178', '4', '222222'], ['192', '178', '5', '1511'], ['192', '178', '6', '999999']]]
```

Comment: If you want to compare the first list to the second list and "replace items in the first list that is different in the second list", why don't you just set the first list equal to the second list?

Comment: I don't understand "set the first list equal to the second list". Both lists are not always uniform in the real data set.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in the OP

Comment: I will do thank you

Comment: Any reason for deleting? your answer works well

Comment: The previous list comprehension didn't work when the nested lists belonging to `list2` were not the same length as the nested lists belonging to `list1`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142873/discussion-between-nobi-and-jacob-g).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you specified that you want to replace values in the first list with values that differ in the second list, I will assume that the size of the second list and its nested lists can only be equal to or larger than the size of the first list and its nested lists.

With this assumption, we can simply set each nested list in `list1` to its respective sliced nested list in `list2`, without the need to compare any values.

```
list1 = [[['192', '177', '4', '749'], ['192', '177', '5', '749'], ['192', '177', '6', '999999']], [['192', '178', '1', '999999'], ['192', '178', '2', '999999'], ['192', '178', '3', '999999'], ['192', '178', '4', '999999'], ['192', '178', '5', '1511'], ['192', '178', '6', '999999']]]

list2 = [[['192', '177', '4', '749'], ['192', '177', '5', '749'], ['192', '177', '6', '222222']], [['192', '178', '1', '222222'], ['192', '178', '2', '222222'], ['192', '178', '3', '222222'], ['192', '178', '4', '222222'], ['192', '178', '5', '1511'], ['192', '178', '6', '999999']]]

list = []

for i in range(len(list2)):
    for j in range(len(list2[i])):
        list.append(list2[i][j][:len(list1[i][j])])
```

I'll see if I can find a good list comprehension for this.